# Laravel Calling response()->file($pathToFile) in a Ajax Modal

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, mime-types, laravel-blade

Since I dont like the default way a file is presented to a user when "return response()->file($pathToFile);" is called I wanted to make a Version in which a file isnt direcly displayed in the current Tab of the Website but rather in a popup Modal - Kind of like how its done when you preview a file in Dropbox.

So what I did is add a button to my view that calls for my Route "preview_modal" This Route then calls my "preview_modal" method in my FileController.
This Method returns the requested File in the Modal.

But sadly when the Mimetype of the requested File is not a "text/*" type of File I get this kind of Text presented to me in my Modal:

```
�PNG  IHDRq�:sRGB���gAMA���a pHYs���o�d   *IDATx^��r�6��~ Ob~��jn9�-��.Q�v˖-��ʥ��`ip���L��d��?�E����'0�0�M�afİ�3Ì6q�a��&�03b���aF����L&�V���H|�̏t[���kȲ�01����,�|�r�b��`����㙮�|:��/���� r/[X�>`�]��KH���5�Oޟa� ��N�A�|��KX��2�:γ�d ٢��,�
```

In this case it was a PNG that was beeing opened. This Text was just a little example.

I have no idea what im looking at If anyone knows what this is i would greatly appreciate it.
The "return response()->file()" works fine for the same file if it isnt called inside the ajax modal.

Button:

```
<button data-path="{{ route('files.preview_modal', $file) }}" class="button is-info load-ajax-modal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dynamic-modal">Preview</button>
```

Ajax Call:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$('.load-ajax-modal').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: $(this).data('path'),

        success: function (result) {
            $('#dynamic-modal div.modal-body').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Route:

```
Route::get('preview_modal/{file}', 'FileController@preview_modal')->name('files.preview_modal');
```

preview_modal Method:

```
public function preview_modal(File $file)
{
  return response()->file(storage_path("$file->path"));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try final these 2 solutions

1. `storage_path("$file->path")` remove double quotes: `storage_path($file->path)`

because you are using variable not the string

2. may be you should convert you image to base64.

   `$path = storage_path($file->path);
   $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $data = file_get_contents($path);
   $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);`

and then use it in html enjoy the day mate :)

Comment: Thanks for all the help i cannot try it right now, but i appreciate it very much thanks!

Comment: Transforming the image to a base64 file did the trick for me. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you are returing whole png as response just return the image name and then whatever the path of the image  use in modal:

```
  <img src="/images/{{ $imageName}}">
```

Comment: I would do that, but the image is stored in the storage folder of laravel since this file belongs to one user. Therefore I cannot access it this way since the storage folder is not accesible publicly. I also cannot make the file public since the public folder that not allow for authentication checks.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the storage folder in public just you have to create the symlink

Execute `php artisan storage:link` for creating symlink in laravel

when you create symlink in laravel then it create symlink of storage/app/public folder to public/storage folder. Its mean that if you want to access any files publicly then place all your files inside storage/app/public folder and access it like this

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/images/test.png')}}" alt="">
```

Here it means the file test.png should be physically at storage/app/public/images/ folder.

or you can create your custom symlink for storage in public folder so you can directly use you storage folder images

```
abc.com/storage/images/picture.png
```

Comment: But couldnt everyone access that certain file if it was in this public folder?
Lets say this file is a invoice. I wouldnt want it to be accessible for the public. Or be found by some kind of crawler.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file = '../image.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
```

Then in your HTML you would reference your any laravel route /outPutImage/ as though it were an image, since that's exactly what it outputs:

```
<img src="appurl.com/outPutImage" />
```

Comment: I will then again just receive the same "error" Text (�PNG  IHDRq�:sRGB���gAMA���a pHYs���o�d) and so forth.

But this time even if its not called via a ajax modal but also when direcly calling it

Comment: I did. This is what i get as a Output.